# RunDisney: Inappropriate Corral Management

Tags: running, long-distance-running

Anyone that has run an organized running event has dealt with the weaving in and out of slower starters that insist on pushing to the front.  It's illogical for most events as they are chip-timed when you cross the starting line, and flat-out rude.  In larger events the weaving could last the whole time.

The Disney runs (half marathon and above) attempt to somewhat relieve this as you are put into starting corrals based times in other running events that must be provable online.  Sure, there will be some attempts at cheating this, but there seems to be a systemic organization to slow runners starting first.

A coworker started a Disney marathon in corral C, elite is A, B is very fast.  He even started at the beginning of C, and still passed an obese man walking the marathon.  And several other slow runners.  How did they get there?

My wife ran the Princess half, and I was shocked at the slow runners that were walking only a half mile into the race.  She spent the whole race weaving in and out of people and added over one mile to her race because of the sideways running (based on the Apple watch and "Map My Run" on her phone).

The most troubling thing is that there were several groups of run-walkers that seemed to be organized by Disney.  These groups were large (over 50 people) and were led by a person carrying a sign advertising the goal pace.  Despite their pace being significantly slower than my wife's, the whole group got to start ahead of her.  The fastest of the group she passed was going at a pace a half hour slower than hers.  How is that reasonable?

Passing these large groups can be very problematic as they tend to take up the whole road.

So my question is do you thing there is a systemic problem with RunDisney's corral placement?  Can a person just pay to be put in an earlier corral?

Answer (score 3):

> He even started at the beginning of C, and still passed an obese man walking the marathon. And several other slow runners. How did they get there?

Fairly often, people who did not register for the race join the race part-way through.

> The fastest of the group she passed was going at a pace a half hour slower than hers. How is that reasonable?

That doesn't seem reasonable.

> So my question is do you thin[k] there is a systemic problem with RunDisney's corral placement? Can a person just pay to be put in an earlier corral?

The [rules](https://www.rundisney.com/disneyworld-marathon/) don't appear to allow different corralling based on participant payment.

Answer (score 3):

RunDisney events suffer from balloon lady fear. Nobody wants to get dropped off of the back to get swept up by the "Bus Of Fail". So people cheat in many different ways. A common way is to get someone else to run your qualifier for you.
RunDisney checks your POT but they don't check it was you who set it. I have had someone admit as much to me at the start of a Disney marathon. If you start in corral A you can start a full hour or more before those pesky balloon ladies. That means you can pace at 18mins a mile rather than the required 16mins a mile. The guy I was talking to got his 23-year-old son to do a qualifier for him. He planned to finish the marathon in about 7-8 hours (He did finish way at the back, I checked). You can't do that unless you start in corral A. You would be swept. So he starts with corral A and just goes backwards with almost the entire marathon field going past him. If you ever do a RunDisney event again go check out the people in corral A. Sometimes the ones who are not there on merit just stand out, you can see there is no way they did the required qualifying time. Also related to balloon lady fear is the slow runners in the correct corrals. They know they are slower and push to the front to give themselves the maximum distance and time between themselves and the balloon ladies. The rest of their corral will normally have to run past them all throughout the course of the run. (The balloon ladies are actually very nice. I started with them after I had a POT rejected.)

Less common is the runner who just joins somewhere after the start (yes they exist). Run in from the woods like you have just been for a pee and nobody will give you a second glance, there are so many people going to the woods to pee.

Those blocks of runners you mention are the ones doing the Geoff Galloway method. If they stick with the person holding the stick, they should finish with the time on the stick. The leaders of those groups are normally experienced pace runners. They can be a pain on narrow sections when they all walk as you are trying to run. My general rule is that it is a Disney fun run and so I'm not really bothered by my own pace during the event, so I just walk with them until I can get past (or they pass me).

I guess you could buy a bib from someone willing to sell it to you. That is about the only way to buy an early coral placement. There is no legitimate way to do that. A race bib is non-transferrable according to the terms and conditions of race entry. I am also pretty confident that this happens. A plump bearded guy in his late 50s who, according to his vest, is named "Brittany" and who is in corral A is always a little bit suspect.

Quick Edit. If you are a Club RunDisney Platinum member you get "Upgraded corral placement" whatever that means.